# Is it possible to create an test automation infrastructure on Docker interacting with BLE/USB devices?

Tags: python, docker, bluetooth-lowenergy, usb

i'm working on a new platform design for my company.

I would like to develop a test automation platform with microservices logic.
This infrastructure will contains Appium Server and Selenium Grid for interacting with mobile and web app.

Furthermore, it will have also a microservice installed on Raspberry Pi4 that will be used to press automatically the button of external devices.

I have a doubt: my external devices need to be paired to the webapp and mobile app via BLE and also via USB. If i dockerize entire platform and execute the test on WebApp/MobileApp, i have the possibility to pair the external devices to them?

I found something online about opening the permission of USB port:

`docker run -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -it <your-container>`

but for BLE?

Summary: The tests execute on webapp and mobile app using a test automation platform dockerized, is it possible to pair external devices via USB/BLE to webapp and mobile app under testing into platform?

I'm scared about it, in particular, i don't know if it is possible to do.

Someone, could help me about it? Explain if it is possible and, if it is possible, how?

Comment: You might have to containerize bluez. Check this out https://medium.com/omi-uulm/how-to-run-containerized-bluetooth-applications-with-bluez-dced9ab767f6

Comment: In general, a Docker container can't interact with host devices.  It's possible to give a container access to a specific device file, but Linux's dynamic USB mapping makes even this tricky, since you don't know which device file it is.